# Why $pull operator doesn't work on MongoDB when using empty criteria?

Tags: mongodb, pull, php-mongodb

I have nodes like this:

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 4e90cb3cd68417740c000017
)
[label] => mystery
[owner] => me
[parents] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => MongoId Object (
            [$id] => 4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca
        )
        [owner] => userid
        [timestamp] => 1318112522
    )
)
[timestamp] => 1318112060
[translabel] => mystery
[type] => 0
```

What I am trying to do is to remove parents with id : 4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca , wherever they are.

For example this should have been working (latest Mongo):

```
db.nodes.update({},{$pull : {"parents": { "id" : ObjectId("4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca") }}});
```

or equaly in PHP (latest driver etc):

```
$mongodb->nodes->update(array(),array('$pull'=> array('parents'=>array('id'=> new MongoId("4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca")))));
```

both don't do anything!

---

on the other hand:

```
db.nodes.update({"_id": ObjectId("4e90cb3cd68417740c000017")},{$pull : {"parents": { "id" : ObjectId("4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca") }}});
```

or equaly in PHP:

```
$mongodb->nodes->update(array('_id' => new MongoId("4e90cb3cd68417740c000017"),array('$pull'=> array('parents'=>array('id'=> new MongoId("4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca")))));
```

work perfectly well! Is this a bug? Is it a problem that I use "id" instead of "_id" with MongoID objects in my subdocuments? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried enable [multi flag](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) on update command

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
```

multi - indicates if all documents matching criteria should be updated rather than just one. Can be useful with the $ operators below.

and change your query  to

```
db.nodes.update({},{$pull : {"parents": { "id" : ObjectId("4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca") }}},false,true);
```

or

```
db.nodes.update({ "_id" : { $exists : true } },{$pull : {"parents": { "id" : ObjectId("4e8c6bb6d68417340e0004ca") }}},false,true);
```

i haven't tested the code myself, but am sure that any one of the above will work..

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The first one works both from Mongo Command and PHP and is what I needed -  Since I have only one node with this parent - can you please explain to me why do I need multi? Is it because I have empty search criteria and this node is not firstly found - so no updates are done?

Comment: Yes absolutely right, because you have empty search criteria and this node is not firstly found. Multi enforces mongodb to update to all documents that matches criteria. In this case criteria is {} (all documents). And you can accept this as answer if helpful...

Comment: great thanks - now it's clear - sorry for the late accept of the answer - It is my first question :)